# Tkinter GUI does not response in (for loop) when clicking or moving mouse

Tags: for-loop, tkinter, python-multithreading

I just wrote a simple automation program to do the test work with Tkinter GUI.
Everything else is fine except whenever I have the actions like move or click mouse, the GUI will not response but the code is still running. After the loop is done, the GUI comes to normal state. Here is part of my code (only for loop, my code is a little long for hardware setting and acquisition for example.)

```
    for i in range(0, loop_number):
        power_supply = str(input.iloc[i][0]).split(',')
        channel1 = int(power_supply[0])
        voltage1 = float(power_supply[1])
        current1 = power_supply[2]
        self.power_channel_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.power_channel_text.insert(1.0, channel1)
        self.voltage_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.voltage_text.insert(1.0, voltage1)
        self.current_compliance_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.current_compliance_text.insert(1.0, current1)

        Aardvark = str(input.iloc[i][2]).split(',')
        register_values = []
        start_address = Aardvark[0]
        for n in range(0, len(Aardvark[1].split(' '))):
            register_values.append(int(Aardvark[1].split(' ')[n], 16))
        self.aardvark_write_Address_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.aardvark_write_Address_text.insert(1.0, start_address)
        self.aardvark_i2c_write_value_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.aardvark_i2c_write_value_text.insert(1.0, str(Aardvark[1]))

        temp = str(input.iloc[i][3]); save_path = str(input.iloc[i][4])
        self.temperature_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.temperature_text.insert(1.0, temp)
        self.save_path_text.delete(1.0, END)
        self.save_path_text.insert(1.0, save_path)
        part = str(input.iloc[i][5]); Label = str(input.iloc[i][6])  
        self.progress_bar['value'] = 5 + step * (i + 1)
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(5)
```

outside the loop, I already initialize my text value and progress bar value. I search online for tutorial and found two solutions. One is using multithread and the other is using after function. However, they are used when there are other trigger events will happen while I have only run button. And after that, I just want to update the text value and progress bar value for each run till end. Could anyone give me some suggestions please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are blocking the GUI from being able to register events because it is too busy executing your code. What you want is to run one iteration of the code, then return control back to the GUI for 5 milliseconds before trying again rather than just sleeping the whole thread. Try the following:

```
def perform_loop(self, remaining):
    if remaining < 0: return

    power_supply = str(input.iloc[i][0]).split(',')
    channel1 = int(power_supply[0])
    voltage1 = float(power_supply[1])
    current1 = power_supply[2]
    self.power_channel_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.power_channel_text.insert(1.0, channel1)
    self.voltage_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.voltage_text.insert(1.0, voltage1)
    self.current_compliance_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.current_compliance_text.insert(1.0, current1)

    Aardvark = str(input.iloc[i][2]).split(',')
    register_values = []
    start_address = Aardvark[0]
    for n in range(0, len(Aardvark[1].split(' '))):
        register_values.append(int(Aardvark[1].split(' ')[n], 16))
    self.aardvark_write_Address_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.aardvark_write_Address_text.insert(1.0, start_address)
    self.aardvark_i2c_write_value_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.aardvark_i2c_write_value_text.insert(1.0, str(Aardvark[1]))

    temp = str(input.iloc[i][3]); save_path = str(input.iloc[i][4])
    self.temperature_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.temperature_text.insert(1.0, temp)
    self.save_path_text.delete(1.0, END)
    self.save_path_text.insert(1.0, save_path)
    part = str(input.iloc[i][5]); Label = str(input.iloc[i][6])  
    self.progress_bar['value'] = 5 + step * (i + 1)
    self.root.update_idletasks()
    self.root.after(5, lambda x: self.perform_loop(remaining - 1))
```

Then just call `perform_loop` with the number of iterations you want to perform before your call to `mainloop` on the GUI.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again and I found some problems of my while codes. I do need some delays in my for loop to wait for my hardware to do acquisition or calculation. My understand is now I cannot use time.sleep method to do the delay. Or just during updating the GUI, I cannot use time.sleep and after or before those pieces of code, I am still able to the the delay. Thank you very much.

Comment: Anywhere you want to use `time.sleep()`, instead split the code below it into a new definition, and where you would have the sleep call `self.root.after(<time>, <function>)` instead. Your code won't be called until after the time period, exactly the same as if you had used sleep, but it will allow the GUI to update in that time, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you again and I modified the code.99.9% is working, however, in my code, I need to acquire data from the scope, during that time, the GUI will freeze anyhow. Though it may happen 1 second for loop, I still want to know is there anyway to fix that? Like multithread? It is more complicated than root.after scheme. I saw some tutorials online and knew the basic already. Still I have no idea how to implement my code with thread. Is there any suggestion??

Comment: Tell me which lines don't run fast enough and I'll edit my answer to fix it.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,I tried that your advice. It is perfect to update the GUI. However, when I tried to acquire the data from the scope, during the acquisition, the GUI will not be responsible. If I commend that out, it is working perfectly. There is nothing wrong with your code. Thank you very much.